# Fastest way of comparing lists of strings

Tags: python

```
A = ['a','b','c'] 
B = ['d','b','e']

res = [i for i in A if i in B]
```

The above code does not work when the no of elements in A are 300000 and in B are 200000.

How can I solve it?

I also tried

```
res = {i for i in A if i in B}
res = list(res)
```

But still could not get the result.

Comment: 'Does not work' what does that mean?

Comment: Change `B` to a set first: `B = set(B)`, then use the list comprehension.

Comment: What about `A = set(A)` and `B = set(B)`, then do the intersection `res = A & B`?

Comment: And what type of comparation you want to do? When comparing lists I assume list are equal if elements are in the same order, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If preserving order and/or duplicates doesn't matter, then you can use

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
B = ['d', 'e', 'f']
res = list(set(A) & set(B))
```

If order and/or duplicates does matter, then you can use

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
B = ['d', 'e', 'f']
set_b = set(B)
res = [i for i in A if i in set_b]
```

Comment: The second one can also be written (although somewhat ugily) as `filter(set(B).__contains_, A)`

Answer (score 3):

```
A = ['a','b','c']
B = ['d','b','e']

set(A).intersection(B)
```

To get a list returned:

```
list(set(A).intersection(B))
```

intersection takes any iterable  as an argument so you just need to make `A` a set.

*Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference() will accept any iterable as an argument.*

Comment: Should that be `(set(B))`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, why would B need be a set?

Comment: This will remove the redundant items from `A` too and also affect the order if it matters, OP's first example is not doing that.

Comment: Not having B a `set` increases the time by 50% on my computer on a test case of the size OP specified

Comment: @deinonychusaur  well if the OP has lists how are they going to magically become sets?

Comment: I was just asking for myself :-) didn't mean to imply this was wrong

Comment: `set(A).intersection(set(B))` if there are redundencies in `B` I assume is the difference in performance

Comment: @TimCastelijns, no worries I thought I might have been missing something

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction, the OP was using a set in the question so I don't think the order or redundant items is an issue.

Comment: @deinonychusaur, there was exactly `.2` of a `ms` difference on a list with 1000 items using `set(A).intersection(set(B))` and `set(A).intersection(B)`

Comment: Only the left-hand side needs to be a set, as shown in the answer here. The intersection operation will proceed by iterating once over the right-hand-side list, grabbing the intersecting elements (by testing if they are `in` the left-hand-side set). This is more efficient because creating a set first would require doing a similar iteration anyway, and then the native set operation.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I was testing with the sizes in specified in the question, but having the second as a `set` is, as I said, only relevant if there are many redundancies in `B`, if there are it will be a significant improvement

Answer (score 1):

You are basically computing the intersection of two sets.  Using the `set` data type for this will make this efficient:

```
A = {'a','b','c'}
B = {'d','b','e'}
res = A & B
```

Comment: how to put the lists A and B into {}?

Comment: @bas just do `set(A) & set(B)`